# jQuery code not working?

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I've been building a development site "http://webdesignsalemoregon.com/lpr-settings-1/" and the jQuery code works just fine.

I cloned a clients site and am trying to get it on the new format "http://webdesignsalemoregon.com/harolds-lpr/"

but it seems like the jQuery code isn't working? It seems to be loaded just fine in the header? :/

EDIT

the custom jquery file is "custom.js"

Comment: You have to make sure to have the jQuery library embed in your page. If you have firebug you can test it in the console with: window.jQuery and it will yield a function()

Comment: As answered by Rocket below... you are loading your `custom.js` file before `jQuery`.  You need to load `jQuery` first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure jQuery is loaded before your scripts.  Looking at the site, it seems your scripts are being loaded before jQuery is, so you're getting "jQuery is not defined" in the console.

Comment: Thanks a bunch - I'm not sure how they got out of order, but I just re-enqueued it well above any custom js files.

thanks! :D